# How to backup mysql database while application is running?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, background-process

What is the prefer way to generate mysql backup while application is running ?

I want to provide functionality to admin to take backup of database at the same time when other admin using the same application from other computer.

What is the prefer way to handling this scenario ?

Comment: Do you use a transactional engine (E.g. innoDB)?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you can take backup using mysqldump utility without stopping the database.  Mysqlworkbench application provides easier interface to do this. If you are looking for a more advanced option and worry about transaction you can set up a replicated server, so that you can take the stable backups without stopping the master server.

Answer (score -2):

if you are working on a webserver with php support use phpMyAdmin or any mySQL Dumper